# Generate a single file with Telosys

Tags: velocity, telosys

how are you? I am learning how to use Telosys to make a code generator for Arduino, I was wondering if there is a way to create a single file for all the entities in my DSL. For example, I have the .entity files "Cars" and "Drivers", which generates me two .txt files when I generate code. Is there any way to generate the code for both .entity files in a single text file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible and it's quite easy.  In your ".vm" file you just have to iterate on each entity defined in the model by using one these entities list : "**$model.allEntites**" or "**$selectedEntities**"
( see templates doc : https://www.telosys.org/templates-doc/objects/model.html )

Here's an example :

```
All entities :
#foreach( $entity in $model.allEntites )
 . $entity.name : $entity.attributesCount attributes
#end
```

The "database doc" is a bundle of templates using this kind of generation.
See "database_tables_list.vm" in bundle https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/database-doc-T300

Don't forget to set the "number of generations" to "**1**" for this ".vm" file in the "**templates.cfg**" file in order to generate it only once

Example from "database doc" bundle ( "**1**" at the end of line ) :

```
Database tables list (HTML) ; database.html ; dbdoc ; database_tables_list.vm  ; 1
```

In your case for a text file :

```
My global text file ; global.txt ; myfolder ; mytemplate.vm  ; 1
```

Comment: Another example to produce an HTML navigation bar :
https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/csharp-web-mvc/blob/master/Views/Shared/_Layout_cshtml.vm